# Rewrite Dynamic URLs to Friendly URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have looked through a lot of different questions that have been answered about how to rewrite a dynamic URL, and for whatever reason I can't get the code they use to work for me. I know I will need to edit the .htaccess file.

Current URL: example.com/search/profileview.php?storeid=1&store=aqua-addicts

Ideal URL: example.com/search/profileview/aqua-addicts.html

If that's not possible, I'd be fine with anything that removes the ?, & and = from the URL. Here is what I'm currently trying in the .htaccess that isn't working.

EDIT: Clarifying isn't working 
I have one page that generates the results based on search criteria. The link from that page is: 
 which is equivalent to 
example.com/search/profileview.php?storeid=1&store=aqua-addicts

I would like to be able to click on the link and have the URL be changed to the friendly version.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profileview\.php\?storeid=([^&]*)&.*?store=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profileview-storeid-%1-store-%2.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^profileview-storeid-([^-]+)-store-([^.]+)\.html$ profileview.php?storeid=$1&store=$2 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Any help is appreciated. I know it's probably a simple change for some, but I've been trying to figure this out for about a day and a half now.

Comment: Instead of *redirecting* old paths to the new scheme, adapt your HTML and PHP scripts to output the new URLs by itself. -- "Isn't working" isn't a very detailed problem description.

Comment: The rule looks ok, please explain what is not working ?

Comment: Sorry, I have one page that generates the results based on search criteria. The link from that page is:

<a href='profileview.php?storeid=$info[storeid]&store=$info[store]'> which is equivalent to example.com/search/profileview.php?storeid=1&store=aqua-addicts

But I would like to be able to click on the link and have the URL be changed to the friendly version. Does that help clarify?

Comment: Search result pages are temporary by nature. They don't really need pretty URLs.

Comment: I guess I need to create a static page for every possible search result, that just seems like a lot of manual effort, I would have thought there is a simpler way. I imagine sites like facebook or linkedin do it some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It doesn't apply the redirect automatically but lets you remove the unwanted ? from the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/profileview/(.*).html?$ search/profileview.php?storeid=$1&store=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

You can then adjust your permalinks like search/profileview/aqua-addicts.html

Comment: Using this, will I need to create a static URL manually for every dynamic URL?

Comment: You don't need to create the URL manually if the value for storeid and store are generated dynamically. Simply use the variable after search/profileview/ which you use to pass the value for store. i.e. dynamic url: search.profileview.php?storeid=<?php echo $storeid;?>&store=<?php echo $store;?> and you will need to adjust your permalinks after rewrite like: search/profileview/<?php echo $store;?>.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/profileview/([^/]+).html search/profileview.php?storeid=1&store=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this did not work for what I was trying to do